# Error at module.js:341 when trying to add android platform to ionic from command line

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, ionic-framework, npm

I am going to use the Ionic framework to work on hybrid app development, so I installed all the necessary dependencies (node.js, cordova, etc.) and followed their [Getting started](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/) section. Step number 3 simply involves running the following command within the app directory:

```
> ionic platform add android
```

However midway during the execution I got the following error:

```
module.js:341
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'config-chain'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\james.bonello\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:2:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
```

I ran `> npm update` first and tried again to see if the update fixes any missing dependencies and such but the problem persisted.

So, as the error clearly states, the module 'config-chain' is missing so I next ran

`> npm install config-chain`

While that did install the module, the error somehow still persisted (identical to the previous one). I am not sure what to do next and I cannot understand why npm is not recognizing the 'config-chain' module now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, the missing package `config-chain` is a dependency of the **global** package `cordova`.

You should re-install cordova:

```
npm cache clean
npm uninstall cordova -g
npm install cordova -g
```

IF the problem persists, you have to manually install the package inside cordova's modules:

```
C:> cd Users\james.bonello\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
C:> npm install config-chain
```

Comment: Cleaning npm and reinstalling Cordova fixed this issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did **npm install** and it worked .

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work - - in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question. This is especially important for an older question and the questions that already have answers.